# Copy columns from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill in the workbook that holds the macro with data from another workbook. The data I need to copy can be on different columns on the source file, depending on the way this source file is generated. So I may run into a problem, because I might get the data I want on a wrong column, or I may even get data I do not want. So I guess it's better to look for the column header (which are always the same string, no matter how the report is generated). I can use the Find method to search for the headers, but how to copy the rows below each header? The range where I want the data pasted are always the same ranges on the paste workbook, and always the first sheet.

Following is my current code:

```
Sub Import()

' Looks up for the Source Report file and imports its data into wkbk that holds the macro

On Error Resume Next

' Defines Source Report file variable
    Dim SourceFile As Variant

' Opens the SourceFile
    MsgBox ("Open the SourceFile")
    SourceFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
    If SourceFile <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=SourceFile
    End If

    SourceFileDir = Dir(SourceFile)

' Looks up the last row on SourceFile to copy the entire data later
    With Workbooks(SourceFileDir).Worksheets(1)
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

' MsgBox ("The last row of data in the Source File is " & LastRow)

' Sets echo off before copying
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Copies SourceFile data into paste file, the one that holds the macro

' Serial Number
    Workbooks(SourceFileDir).Worksheets(1).Range("E7:E" & LastRow).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A38").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

' Product ID
    Workbooks(SourceFileDir).Worksheets(1).Range("A7:A" & LastRow).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B38").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

' Gets out of copy mode
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

' Sets echo back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The total number of columns I need is 9, the code above just shows two of them, Serial Number and Product ID.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've noticed you are using A38, B38 ... Don't you also want to calculate the last row there? Are the headers in the source sheet always in the first row?

Comment: Well, row 38 is the place in the "paste" workbook where I want the copied cells placed; rows from 1 to 37 are treated as headers in that workbook. If you mean calculate the last row in the "copy" or source workbook, it's there in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workbook to Workbook

Adjust the values in the constants section and right below in the Headers array.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import()

' Looks up for the Source Report file and imports its data into
' wkbk that holds the macro

    Const LastRowColumnS As Long = 1
    Const FirstRowS = 7
    Const FirstRowP = 38

    Dim Headers As Variant
    Headers = Array("Serial Number", "Product ID", "ID", _
      "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", _
      "Name7", "Name8", "Name9")

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SourceFile As Variant
    Dim wsS As Worksheet
    Dim wsP As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowS As Long
    Dim CurColS As Long
    Dim CurColP As Long
    Dim NumberOfRows As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Opens Source File.
    MsgBox ("Open the SourceFile")
    SourceFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
      FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
    If SourceFile <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=SourceFile
    Else
        MsgBox "You selected cancel."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Define worksheets.
    Set wsS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    ' Define last cell with data in Last Row Column of Source Sheet.
    Set rng = wsS.Columns(LastRowColumnS).Find( _
        What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data in column."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    NumberOfRows = rng.Row - FirstRowS + 1

    For i = 0 To UBound(Headers)
        ' Define column of Current Header in Source Sheet.
        Set rng = wsS.Cells.Find(What:=Headers(i), _
          After:=wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.Count, wsS.Columns.Count), _
          LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            CurColS = rng.Column
            ' Define column of Current Header in Paste Sheet.
            Set rng = wsP.Cells.Find(What:=Headers(i), _
              After:=wsP.Cells(wsP.Rows.Count, wsP.Columns.Count), _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                CurColP = rng.Column
                ' Write data from Source Sheet to Paste Sheet.
                wsP.Cells(FirstRowP, CurColP).Resize(NumberOfRows).Value _
                  = wsS.Cells(FirstRowS, CurColS).Resize(NumberOfRows).Value
                ' Count the transfer.
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ' Maybe close Source Workbook.
    'wsS.Parent.Close False

    MsgBox "Transferred data from '" & Count & "' columns."


End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Since some of the headers have different values (names) on each sheet you should use two arrays (one for each sheet) and adjust the values appropriately:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import()

' Looks up for the Source Report file and imports its data into
' wkbk that holds the macro

    Const LastRowColumnS As Long = 1
    Const FirstRowS = 7
    Const FirstRowP = 38

    Dim HeadSource As Variant
    Dim HeadPaste As Variant
    HeadSource = Array("Serial Number", "Product ID", "ID", _
      "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", _
      "Name7", "Name8", "Name9")
    HeadPaste = Array("Serial Number", "Product ID", "ID", _
      "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", _
      "Name7", "Name8", "Name9")

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SourceFile As Variant
    Dim wsS As Worksheet
    Dim wsP As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowS As Long
    Dim CurColS As Long
    Dim CurColP As Long
    Dim NumberOfRows As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Opens Source File.
    MsgBox ("Open the SourceFile")
    SourceFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
      FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
    If SourceFile <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=SourceFile
    Else
        MsgBox "You selected cancel."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Define worksheets.
    Set wsS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    ' Define last cell with data in Last Row Column of Source Sheet.
    Set rng = wsS.Columns(LastRowColumnS).Find( _
        What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data in column."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    NumberOfRows = rng.Row - FirstRowS + 1

    For i = 0 To UBound(HeadSource)
        ' Define column of Current Header in Source Sheet.
        Set rng = wsS.Cells.Find(What:=HeadSource(i), _
          After:=wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.Count, wsS.Columns.Count), _
          LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            CurColS = rng.Column
            ' Define column of Current Header in Paste Sheet.
            Set rng = wsP.Cells.Find(What:=HeadPaste(i), _
              After:=wsP.Cells(wsP.Rows.Count, wsP.Columns.Count), _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                CurColP = rng.Column
                ' Write data from Source Sheet to Paste Sheet.
                wsP.Cells(FirstRowP, CurColP).Resize(NumberOfRows).Value _
                  = wsS.Cells(FirstRowS, CurColS).Resize(NumberOfRows).Value
                ' Count the transfer.
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ' Maybe close Source Workbook.
    'wsS.Parent.Close False

    MsgBox "Transferred data from '" & Count & "' columns."


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it is a very complete solution. The only problem is, in the "Paste" sheet, only two of the headers are the same as in the "Source" sheet, the other 7 have different names. I tried your code and only those 2 were correctly transferred. Should I add another array on the code for the names of those 7 headers?

Comment: @EduardoChavarría: I've edited my answer. You are almost right. You should use two arrays and adjust the values. Some of them will be the same, others will not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this new version and will let you know the outcome.